# VBA - Click a JS button on Morningstar.com

Tags: javascript, vba, excel

During my search on stackoverflow, I found a number of topics similar to this without solid answers. What I am trying to do is go to the website below and click on the "Export CSV" JS button.

So far what I have "copied and borrowed" from another VBA Coder is:

Sub GetDat()

```
Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

With IE
    .Visible = True
    .navigate "http://financials.morningstar.com/ratios/r.html?t=JNJ&region=USA&culture=en_US"
    .Top = 50
    .Left = 530
    .Height = 600
    .Width = 1000

Do Until Not IE.Busy And IE.readyState = 4
    DoEvents
Loop

End With

IE.Document.getelementsbytagname("Export").Item(1).Click
```

End Sub

I have tried delaying it by 5-10 seconds to wait for the page to load. Someone referred to the getelementsbytagname is not finding the button...?

Also, I inspected the element of the button. The html for the button is (I added spaces to show the whole code):

> < a class="large_button" href="javascript:exportKeyStat2CSV();" >< span class="csv" >< /span >< div >Export< /div >< /a >

Thank you for your time, looking forward to hearing any ideas on how I can figure this out!

Comment: Is there a particular reason you want to do this in IE? Even if you succeed in this step, handling the download dialogue is much more difficult. You'd be much better off downloading directly

Comment: Actually, I would prefer to use Chrome. However, the only examples I have seen used IE. I was under the impression that all Microsoft programs will be able to work better together. At this point, I have excel pull up the webpage for me, then I manually click the link. Of course, I would like it be fully automated if it's possible.

Comment: You shouldn't be using a browser at all to simply download a file, try the below

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't be using a browser to simply download files, using the `URLDownloadToFileA` API:

```
Private Declare Function URLDownloadToFile Lib "urlmon" Alias "URLDownloadToFileA" (ByVal pCaller As Long, _
    ByVal szURL As String, ByVal szFileName As String, _
    ByVal dwReserved As Long, ByVal lpfnCB As Long) As Long

Sub Download()
    URLDownloadToFile 0, "http://financials.morningstar.com/ajax/exportKR2CSV.html?&callback=?&t=XNYS:JNJ&region=usa&culture=en-US&cur=&order=asc", _
                         "C:\Temp\Export.csv", 0, 0
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for your response Kyle. This is all beyond my skill set so I will have to research it. I'm getting a compile error: Only comments may appear after End Sub...etc. I will do more research! Thanks again!

Comment: Just put it in a blank module as it is. API declarations must be at the top